# Error in installing csi driver to a Kubernetes cluster v1.16

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am a Kubernetes novice. I am trying to install a csi driver to a Kubernetes Namespace in a kubernetes cluster version 1.16.15.

I am using helm 2.16 version to do the install using below command :

`.\helm install --name csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver --namespace csi --debug`

```
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '63250'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:63250"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] Fetched secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver to C:\Users\XXX\.helm\cache\archive\secrets-store-csi-driver-0.0.19.tgz

[debug] CHART PATH: C:\Users\XXX\.helm\cache\archive\secrets-store-csi-driver-0.0.19.tgz

**Error: render error in "secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/csidriver.yaml": template: secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/_helpers.tpl:40:45: executing "csidriver.apiVersion" at <.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version>: can't evaluate field Version in type *version.Info**
```

csidriver.yaml :

```yaml
    apiVersion: {{ template "csidriver.apiVersion" . }}
    kind: CSIDriver
    metadata:
      name: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
    spec:
      podInfoOnMount: true
      attachRequired: false
    {{- if semverCompare ">=1.16-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version }}
      # Added in Kubernetes 1.16 with default mode of Persistent. Secrets store csi driver needs Ephermeral to be set.
      volumeLifecycleModes: 
      - Ephemeral
    {{ end }}
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: That is almost certainly caused by using an outdated helm version. Helm v2 is not the modern version. Try with [a modern helm version](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/)

Comment: Can you please share the helm chart link as well? It seems the error is pointing out to the incorrect apiVersion being used and is not able to render one of the fields in CRD for the same.

Comment: I ran the install using Helm 3 and it fixed the issue. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by old `Helm` version.
Problem was resolved after upgrading to the new `Helm v3`.

There is helpful [guide](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/) on how to migrate `Helm v2` to `v3`.